# grouped forest plot for multiple ORs

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-forestplot

I'm trying to recreate this forest plot with grouped ORs:

[image: Goal forest plot]

This is the code that I'm using (see the data at the bottom of the question):

```
colnames(Forest_plot_for_univariate_analysis)[1]<-"id"`
Forest_plot_for_univariate_analysis$pe <- log(Forest_plot_for_univariate_analysis$OR)

Forest_plot_for_univariate_analysis$ci.l <- log(Forest_plot_for_univariate_analysis$lci)

Forest_plot_for_univariate_analysis$ci.u <- log(Forest_plot_for_univariate_analysis$uci)

blobbogram('Forest_plot_for_univariate_analysis', group.labels=c('Group'),
columns=c('p', 'phet'), column.labels=c('p', 'phet'),
column.groups=c(2), grouped=TRUE,
column.group.labels=c('CKD', 'eGFR', 'UACR'),
id.label="Stroke subtype", ci.label="OR (95% CI)", log.scale=TRUE, draw.no.effect=TRUE)
```

But I get this error message:

> 'Error in data[["group"]] : subscript out of bounds'`

Any idea where I'm going wrong? Also open to alternative suggestions of how to recreate this graph.

```
dput(Forest_plot_for_univariate_analysis)
structure(list(id = c("All stroke", "Ischaemic stroke", "Large artery stroke", 
"Small vessel stroke", "Cardioembolic stroke", "Intracerebral haemorrhage", 
"All stroke", "Ischaemic stroke", "Large artery stroke", "Small vessel stroke", 
"Cardioembolic stroke", "Intracerebral haemorrhage", "All stroke", 
"Ischaemic stroke", "Large artery stroke", "Small vessel stroke", 
"Cardioembolic stroke", "Intracerebral haemorrhage"), Group = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), OR = c(1.067, 
1.066, 0.903, 0.988, 1.036, 1.08, 1.824, 1.881, 3.146, 1.914, 
1.346, 3.083, 1.232, 1.154, 1.478, 1.468, 1.22, 3.699), lci = c(0.982, 
1.007, 0.77, 0.844, 0.928, 0.799, 1.261, 1.246, 1.276, 0.824, 
0.672, 0.417, 0.917, 0.83, 0.733, 0.723, 0.61, 0.721), uci = c(1.161, 
1.129, 1.06, 1.158, 1.156, 1.461, 2.635, 2.841, 7.752, 4.437, 
2.697, 22.76, 1.659, 1.602, 2.983, 2.983, 2.442, 18.973), p = c(0.016, 
0.027, 0.21, 0.885, 0.534, 0.618, 0.001, 0.003, 0.013, 0.131, 
0.402, 0.27, 0.167, 0.395, 0.274, 0.288, 0.575, 0.117), phet = c(0.656, 
0.584, 0.276, 0.096, 0.59, 0.548, 3e-04, 0.001, 0.075, 0.03, 
0.144, 0.079, 0.292, 0.232, 0.818, 0.329, 0.027, 0.361), pe = c(0.0648509723196163, 
0.0639133257436529, -0.102032725565152, -0.0120725812342692, 
0.0353671438372913, 0.0769610411361284, 0.60103189165214, 0.631803550318893, 
1.14613180463609, 0.649195293030763, 0.297137231222536, 1.12590314890401, 
0.208638865111328, 0.143234168085908, 0.39068982252601, 0.383900930192324, 
0.198850858745165, 1.30806251285032), ci.l = c(-0.0181639706276712, 
0.00697561373642514, -0.261364764134408, -0.16960278438618, -0.0747235461959364, 
-0.224394333215862, 0.231905056982782, 0.219938420365261, 0.243730184922598, 
-0.193584749072665, -0.397496938458987, -0.874669057183336, -0.0866478067256722, 
-0.186329578191493, -0.310609577095486, -0.324346056823372, -0.49429632181478, 
-0.327116141697188), ci.u = c(0.149281702715754, 0.121332285167525, 
0.0582689081239758, 0.146694379150803, 0.144965770250186, 0.379121132768562, 
0.968883181993326, 1.04415610287205, 2.04795087458846, 1.48997847239677, 
0.992140044157593, 3.12500460925813, 0.506215011208307, 0.471252848646168, 
1.09292950553261, 1.09292950553261, 0.892817375688513, 2.943016915882
)), row.names = c(NA, -18L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

[Here is an image of my dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FH5dO.png)

Comment: Could you please share your data using `dput(df)`? So we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: Thanks - I've edited the above function to add dput(df)